# C++ program that catches SIGKILL under Linux

Tags: c++, signals, kill, coredump

I want to create a coredump when my process receives the SIGKILL in linux.
I try to catch this signal, but it seems that SIGKILL can't be caught.

Comment: You are correct. `SIGKILL` cannot be caught. That's how Linux and Unix have worked for the last 50 years, or so. I, somehow, doubt that this will ever change.

Comment: Thanks! I think that is not a good idea. i'll try some other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, As per the [`man` page for `sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html):

> `signum` specifies the signal and can be any valid signal except `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`.

This has pretty much been the case forever, you really *don't* want to give a process the ability to handle *all* signals since that would allow you to get to a point where it can only be killed by a power cycle :-)